# How do those who hold to a literal interpretation of the flood account respond to the criticism that Noah building the ark would be unfeasible?

Tags: genesis, flood-of-noah, literalism, ark-of-noah

In Longman and Walton's book *The Lost World of the Flood* (2018) they argue that the account of Noah's flood in the book of Genesis, although based on an historical event, employs rhetorical devices such as **hyperbole**. One example of this is the size of the ark. In the Genesis account, the size of the ark is put at 450 feet long, 75 feet wide, and 45 feet high (estimates vary, but that is the approximate size).

As the authors say (p. 39),

> "Let's remember that the ark as described in the Bible, if taken as
> precise measurements of an actual boat, **is larger than any wooden boat
> built not just in antiquity but at any time, including today**. [...]
> the earliest vessels, rarely more than ten feet in length [...]
> Egyptian art [...] depicts ships that may be as long as 170 feet [...]
> Even once we move into Roman times [...] the most famous large vessel
> was the Isis [...] Remarkably, it was 180 feet by 45 feet by 44 feet -
> less than a quarter the size of the ark.
>
> Moving to more recent times [...] The USS Dunderberg is often listed
> at the longest at 377 feet, but 50 feet of the length is a ram, so to
> compare to the ark we should list it at 327. The Wyoming [...] is
> listed at 449 feet, but this includes the jib-boom; actually it is 329
> feet. These modern long wooden boats are also built with iron bolts
> and steel supports, something not available to Noah."

According to Longman and Walton, unlike a contemporary reader who is used to boats the size of the ark or bigger (such as cargo ships or cruise-liners - indeed, this is small compared to the largest ships nowadays - the largest cruise ship is 1,200 feet long and 210 feet wide), an ancient reader would have immediately recognized this as an unprecedentedly huge ship which would have been virtually impossible for Noah and his family to build (or perhaps even the King's navy).

Hence, they argue, it is plausible to hold an ancient reader would have readily seen this as 'obvious' hyberbole, similar to a person nowadays saying "this luggage weighs 10,000 pounds" - any listener nowadays would know that latter phrase is meant as hyperbole for effect.

What are the main responses to this type of argument? There are two main aspects here. First, do those who hold the flood story is to be understood literally hold this actually would be a practical achievement by Noah and his family, and if so how? Second, are there any common responses to the argument it is reasonable to hold this would have been seen by ancient listeners as hyperbole, who would never have seen boats of this size?

Comment: I don't think people didn't build massive wooden ships because it was technically infeasible, but because there was generally no advantages to doing so, because the larger the ship the more difficult propulsion and navigation were. If you just wanted a giant floating box you wouldn't have cared about these reasons. Also, Ptolemy IV built an impractically-large showoff ship, a "forty", that was ~425ft long and required 4k (!) rowers.

Comment: @Shamshiel Right, but Ptolemy IV was a Pharaoh! It was a showoff ship precisely because it would have taken a very large amount of resources to build, no?

Comment: The *resources* aren't really that extraordinary, particular if timber and labor were plentiful, as they were in antiquity. For example, Brian Devereaux (okay history blog) estimates that providing the metal goods required to outfit a single Roman legion took approximately 5100 tons of timber. Or more navally, the popular 150ft quinquireme was about 100 tons of timber, which, solely in timber-felling and cording work, would have been about 50 days of labor.But it was a show-off ship because it was so huge as to be impractical to use; Plutarch said it was dangerous to ever move it in the water!

Comment: Just doing some Very Bad Math, the above dimensions of the Ark are not far from four or five quinqueremes, at ~150x15ft. The Romans had no problem building a hundred of these at a time as their first exercise in shipbuilding.

Comment: @Shamshiel Would the ship-building process scale similarly? For example, would building a ship 450x75x45 be comparable to building 10 ships 50x7x4?

Comment: In this case it’s much easier to design and build the bigger ship, because you don’t need to design around speed, maneuverability, ramming, or oarsmen. It just needs to float. These were the main engineering challenges. I don’t see any obstacles to size, if that’s all you cared about.

Comment: @Shamshiel Aha! Thanks for this. So the key is that Noah's requirements would have been just to float around like a cork, while in typical ship building the requirements are very different.

Comment: Yes, exactly. In warships, which I know the most about, the requirements really constrained the size - the ship had to be small enough to be regularly beached to dry out and to be very fast and agile while retaining enough mass to be a devastating ram but not a good target. The 390ft temporary Russian timber ships in one answer are probably a closer model, but they were limited by the size of the river and still had to be maneuvered by oarsmen.

Comment: *"[Iron bolts were] something not available to Noah."* Some adherents disagree.

Comment: It's worth remembering that boat building was a craft (i.e. not science-based engineering) until Brunel's time. Boat builders learned their craft, and stuck with a library of proven designs. The client might want a few tweaks, but they got a variant on a proven design. ("Proven" means that boats of this type didn't sink too often).
If the client's requirements were too ambitious, the boat builder would suggest that the client go somewhere else, but some clients couldn't be refused. Maybe Google the Vasa?

Comment: @Shamshiel "I don't think people didn't build massive wooden ships because it was technically infeasible, but because there was generally no advantages to doing so, because the larger the ship the more difficult propulsion and navigation were. If you just wanted a giant floating box you wouldn't have cared about these reasons." Why would you not care about navigation? Three quarters of the Earth is water. Why would you expect a ship without propulsion or navigation to end up on land?

Comment: Normal ships don't have to deal with the turbulence of a flood, or of having to support themselves on land (unless it ended up on a perfectly flat piece of land, it would have to be strong enough to not break apart from the stress of some part of its base being supported and others not).

Comment: @Acccumulation: you’re starting out inland, all you need is an anchor and maybe not even that - he didn’t choose where he stopped. As for breaking apart, wood is very strong, especially the more of it you use (cf the Russian timber ships) and we don’t know whether it broke up on the mountain or not.

Comment: @Acccumulation: indeed based on the story the ship was stuck for quite some time before they could see what it was stuck on, and since Noah had to open a window to release the dove, it sounds like the deck was not accessible from the inside.

Answer (score 24):

Well.

Turns out a bunch of Christians "put their money where their mouths are" and [*actually built the thing*](https://arkencounter.com/). I'd say that pretty well puts to rest any ridiculous claims about it being "impossible".

What about the usual arguments against?

> Noah didn't have the knowledge (wasn't a shipwright) or technology

Really? Do we *know* that? Even if he wasn't, he had plenty of time to *learn*, perhaps up to *120 years*, and metal-working — not just bronze, either, but *iron* — was known pre-Flood (Genesis 4:20–22). Another issue is that Materialists tend to be Progressives (meaning, they believe that history shows a continual "upward" trend). In fact, this notion has been fairly well debunked, and artifacts such as the Antikythera mechanism show that ancient humans were no slouches, intellectually. (Or look at the Pyramids, Colosseum, or Damascus steel.) The idea that ancient humans were "dumb", or technologically backward, is a Materialist assertion that is not only contrary to the Bible, but is often unsupported by the evidence. The idea that ancients couldn't build mega-structures is *so* blatantly wrong that it's absurd that anyone would believe such an idea. (Keep in mind, too, the Pyramids were built *after* both the Flood and Babel, two events that would have had a *significant* detrimental impact on the level of technology in practice.)

> Comparably-sized ships aren't seaworthy

Critics like to point to the [Wyoming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wyoming_(schooner)) as proof that the Ark couldn't possible be seaworthy. It's true that the Wyoming sank... after *more than ten years* of service. The Ark only needed to survive one, and didn't need to try to navigate. Moreover, the Wyoming was built using construction techniques that are known to be problematic (partly because those methods are *fast* and minimize material cost). Other methods are known to be superior, and there is [evidence](https://answersingenesis.org/noahs-ark/the-large-ships-of-antiquity/) that ancients had comparably-sized or even larger ships. Computer modeling has also shown that the Ark would be seaworthy, even in waves up to 30m (typical tsunamis might have 10m waves), and that it could tilt as much as 60° and still right itself.

> Noah couldn't have built it by himself / didn't have the budget

First off, Noah had up to *120 years* to build the ark. That's a long time. Also, he had a family (including older relatives that hadn't died yet) and nothing tells us he couldn't have also *hired* help. (Noah might have been obscenely wealthy; we don't know. Even if he wasn't, he would have known that any wealth he or his family might have had was about to become worthless, which would have freed him to spend it... and even if *that* isn't the case, he still had *decades* in which to work.)

> An ancient reader would have readily seen [the size of the ark] as 'obvious' hyperbole

That may be so... but just because something *seems* exaggerated doesn't mean it *is*. (To compare to the luggage example, I'm not aware of stable containment for neutronium, but if I tell you my suitcase weighs 400 pounds, am I exaggerating, or lugging around depleted uranium for some reason? If I tell some country hick that's never seen a *brick* building, much less one made of metal, that I went to the city and the buildings must have been a thousand feet high, am I exaggerating? If I tell you that some war was so bloody there must have been *millions* of casualties, am I exaggerating?) Anyone that stopped to think would realize that you'd need a pretty big ark to carry all the animals and their food. People close to the event (e.g. Noah's grandkids) would have realized that the recollection was impressive, but still real. To be fair, there isn't really a refutation for this, other than that sometimes *reality is impressive*.

Really, though, the most convincing response would be to go out and replicate Noah's construction. And *we did*.

Comment: +1 "though, the most convincing response would be to go out and replicate Noah's construction. And we did." Why do you feel this is convincing? Was it built with similar tools available to Noah? Has Ham's ark ever been sea tested? And so on.

Comment: @OneGodtheFather, the tools aren't entirely relevant. The Bible records that pre-Flood humans had at least some metal-working, and quality of tools is usually a trade-off against time, not against what *can* be done. It's hard to say "you couldn't build an X" to someone *standing next to an X*, because such a claim is clearly absurd. No, the AA ark (why is it "Ham's" ark?) hasn't been on water, but it's been modeled and shown that the *dimensions* are about as good as you can get; an amazing coincidence if we were so backwards as critics would claim. (And see the Wyoming.)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139776/discussion-on-answer-by-matthew-how-do-those-who-hold-to-a-literal-interpretatio).

Comment: [Woodmorappe's Feasibility Study](https://www.amazon.com/Noahs-Ark-Feasibility-John-Woodmorappe/dp/0932766412) is probably the most indepth defence of the feasibility of the flood narrative, and includes a section on the construction of the ark. Of course it also has its critics, but this isn't a place to detail opposing arguments to a historical global flood.

Comment: Please take extra comments to chat!

Comment: Does the Ark Encounter Ark actually float? Is it built using techniques available at Noah's time? The about page does call it a **modern** engineering marvel!

Comment: The "Ark Encounter" is not a boat.  It is a wooden building with a concrete first floor.  It is permanently on land.  It cannot float.  It is made of modern materials (laminated wood beams and plywood, outside of the concrete backbone it is built on.)  It is very far from being a functional "Noah's Ark."  It is an artist's concept of what the Ark might have looked like given the description in the Bible.

Comment: "The Ark only had to survive one [year], and didn't need to try and navigate".  But what did it have to survive one year of?  According to those that believe in a global flood and a young earth, the answer is:  the waters bursting from the deep in a catalclysm large enough to create mountains, the grand canyon, and disperse fossils all around the globe.   The ark isn't experiencing rain which slowly carries it to mountain tops, it's experiencing the worst seas (by far!) in the history of maritime travel.  Could God have protected the ark through this?  Of course.  But at some point, ....

Comment: God's hand is so heavy in the process that it would have made more sense for him to simply Thanos-snap to get His desired end.

Comment: The Wyoming was built in the 20th century, using techniques and technology not available to Noah, wasn't as bi as the ark and yet still didn't last long.

Comment: The Wyoming? According to your link: "Because of her extreme length and wood construction, Wyoming tended to flex in heavy seas, which would cause the long planks to twist and buckle, thereby allowing sea water to intrude into the hold. Wyoming had to use pumps to keep her hold relatively free of water." So who pumped the water our of the Ark? The elephants? Joan?

Comment: I'd say Mr. Ham's ark puts to rest any claims that it *is* possible. Ham's ark cost tens of millions of dollars to build, was built by a large team, and would not float in a flood. They have thus far also been unable to put actual animals in it (aside from a small petting zoo) when housing animals was the very purpose of the ark. They've successfully built a *museum* about Noah's Ark, but not a *replica* of Noah's Ark by a long shot.

Comment: @KefSchecter, "They have thus far also been unable to put actual animals in it", seriously? What, exactly, is preventing them from doing so? I can almost guarantee its either laws / welfare concerns, or tractability of the animals, which wouldn't be problems for Noah. And a small group (especially able to harvest the needed wood themselves) working over a longer time could do the same work with much lower cost. Like most scoffers, you're just rationalizing your decision to not believe.

Comment: @Matthew Why wouldn't they be problems for Noah? The flood lasted for 40 days and 40 nights. That is not a trivial amount of time; welfare would certainly be an issue. Also, whether I believe or not is neither here nor there; let's focus on the plausibility of the ark.

Answer (score 19):

If you don't accept the underlying premise of this story that there is a God who interacts with his creation and is perfectly capable of doing things that would naturally be impossible (i.e. what we call miracles) then you are going to find a *lot* more wrong in this story than just the feasibility of building the ark. For example, how did Noah know there was a flood coming (lucky guess?), how did the animals 'know' to come to Noah, why didn't the predator animals eat the others, how did he gather and carry enough food of all the different animals' diets? The list could go on.

There are other stories in the Bible of people attaining miraculous results with limited resources - Elijah and the widow of Zarephath, Jesus feeding the 5000 to name but two.

Why would such a God not miraculously multiply Noah's efforts in building the ark, and also keep the ark safe and seaworthy during the flood itself?

You can look for a naturalistic explanation if you want to, and there's nothing wrong with this. But whether or not we find one says nothing about the credibility of the story.

Comment: Yes.
The Flood was:
1) a local event that transformed into a legend that was incorporated into the Bible;
2) an actual event, but not involving anything supernatural; 
3) an actual event, orchestrated by God.
— It is far too common an argument to logically attack the second case, presenting the obvious victory as if it defeats the third.

Comment: ...and the problem with (1) — if it was local — is that either God *lied*, or the bit about the rainbow is a complete fabrication. If it was local, 1 Peter 3 and 2 Peter 3 are wrong. If it was local, why was there an ark *at all*? 70-120 years is *plenty* of time to just *go somewhere else*. The idea of a local flood is *complete nonsense*.

Comment: If you attribute miraculous explanations for things that are naturally impossible (especially when no explicit mention of a miracle seems to appear in the text of this story), how do you differentiate true stories involving miracles from fictional or exaggerated stories?

Comment: +1 "You can look for a naturalistic explanation if you want to, and there's nothing wrong with this. But whether or not we find one says nothing about the credibility of the story." I think this is creating a bit of a false dichotomy. You can hold the story utilizes hyperbole to make a theological point, while also holding God guided Noah and helped him in various ways through providence, no?

Comment: The issue with most attempts to debunk the events related in the Bible is that they begin with the premise that *God didn't do it*, and some people arguing this way don't even seem to realize that they're attacking a straw man.

Comment: @NotThatGuy "how do you differentiate true stories involving miracles from fiction..." A very fair question. You can look at whether God is portrayed in a way consistent with what we know about his character. But I don't think these stories were written with the purpose of persuading a skeptic, and I don't think skeptics will be persuaded in this way.

Comment: @NotThatGuy (Actually in this particular case there _is_ explicit mention of a miracle: 'So God said to Noah, “I am going to put an end to all people, for the earth is filled with violence because of them. I am surely going to destroy both them and the earth."' Gen 6:13. You'd have to read the text very carelessly to come away thinking the flood was a natural event.)

Comment: @IanGoldby I probably phrased that poorly. I meant the way the ark was built is not written as being miraculous, regardless of whether or not the flood itself is written as being miraculous/non-natural (one could argue the latter either way, e.g. if one believes God acted through nature, and if one detail of a story is said to be miraculous, that doesn't mean we should necessarily treat other details as also miraculous). But fair enough on these stories not persuading skeptics (I'll refrain from getting into an extended discussion in the comments about the underlying epistemology there).

Comment: @Matthew says "*The idea of a local flood is complete nonsense.*". But whether it is is irrelevant when listing the explanations generally associated with this event.

Answer (score 9):

With respect to the narrow claim of feasibility, I was surprised recently to learn about the existence of [Russian disposable timber ships](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disposable_ship). Wikipedia says that a [belyana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belyana) could be up to 390 ft long. That's not 450 ft, but it's not far off. It also says that the ships were first built without nails or pitch.

In sharing this fact it is not my intention to take a position one way or another about the historicity of the flood narrative.